# same table not using index in different DBs

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, database-performance, query-performance

I have a production set up and a dev set up for the same database. There is one table which has 80 million records in prodution and it has lesser number of rows in dev. Both the tables has same date index. But in the production table when I use EXPLAIN, I can see that the query is not using any index and scans all the rows. But it dev table, EXPLAIN shows it is using date index as the type is 'range' and key is 'date'. Why it is happening like this  ?

My query is as follows :

```
SELECT date(date) as date, SUM(amount) AS points FROM my_table 
WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-04-17' AND '2014-04-23' 
AND status NOT IN (3,4) AND type NOT IN (5) 
GROUP BY date(date) ORDER BY date DESC.
```

I have another compound index with 'date', 'type' and 'status'. But it is not using it either. I tried with and without GROUP BY. Because of this issue my query often timed out in production.

Comment: Its returning only 6-7 rows as it is mainly to calculate the sum for a week

Comment: Is you date field a date or a datetime field?

Comment: Might be worth changing the 2 dates for your date range to datetime values. Also your query will not bring back any row from you table for 2014-04-24 unless the time is 00:00:00 (ie it will convert the date `2014-04-23` to the datetime `2014-03-23 00:00:00` , and then when it checks if `2014-03-23 00:01:00` is within the range it will decide it is bigger than the max range).

Answer (score 1):

This happens due to index de-fragmentation, first execute analyze table on your server where index is not using properly.

Note: As you mentioned in your query that both servers have different size of table then mysql may use different index as per its own intelligence. You can use force index if you know best option for your query.

```
Analyze table mytable;
```

Then check if still index is not using then you need to rebuild index, you can use below command but it will lock your table for a long time as per table size, so downtime will be required.

```
optimize table mytable;
```

If you don't want to go with them then you can force the appropriate index.

```
SELECT date(date) as date, SUM(amount) AS points FROM my_table force index(myindex) 
WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-04-17' AND '2014-04-23' 
AND status NOT IN (3,4) AND type NOT IN (5) 
GROUP BY date(date) ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks @Zafar. I just tried with the force index option and it reduced the rows from 80 million to 20 million as it is using range.  I will try the other things too.